# Can you help me understand this message?

Tags: cipher, word-sequence

```
0o3qw3 o35 j3 ij92 8r 697 j33e j943 8jr94jq589h
```

I will post the hints if required.

- I received an email with above message.

Comment: Think about adding some more information, and the first "If" should be an "I" I guess.

Comment: Lots of numbers. Have a look at your keyboard. (And some of the j's seem to be off.)

Comment: @MOehm, yes you are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Please let me kmow if you meed more imformation

If it looks like typoes, you are correct in more than one way.

> The cipher works by ”typoing” everything, or pressing the vertically adjacent key on a physical qwerty keyboard.

Comment: It would be nice if you could describe the cipher briefly in your answer.

Comment: Yes, of course.